# restricted by firewall to on-premises location

Tags: sql-server, azure, cloud, firewall, windows-firewall

I am completely new to azure and cloud development. So even if it's a silly question please have some patient.

if a server firewall restricted to connected from only a company's on-premises location what other alternative is possible to do.

> **connection is restricted by firewall which only allows connection from Company-X on-premises location**

I have create an application and now i need it to communicate with on-premises servers, Since the server which i am trying to connect only allow to be connected from the company's location how i am suppose to get connected from other location's.

I have search a lot for the solution but couldn't find anything or may i am not smart enough to understand it, Could anyone kindly explain it to me how it can be done !

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? you created an application and you need it to communicate with on-premises servers?

Comment: @BrunoFaria Yes, I have create an application and now i need it to communicate with on-premises servers, Since the server which i am trying to connect only allow to be connected from the company's location how i am suppose to get connected from other location's

Comment: @ChristoferHansen Azure sql service or sql server install on Azure VM?

Answer (score 1):

So if I understand correctly, you have an application that is deployed in Azure and you want it to talk to a server inside your corporate network. In that case, you have several options:

- If you've deployed to a web app, you can use what is called a "Hybrid Connection", in which you deploy an agent-type application to your network to make the connection
- You can publish the on-prem application using AzureAD Application Proxy and access it from the internet using an AzureAD credential

If you've deployed to a virtual machine, you can go with VPN:

- VPN Site-to-site connection, in which you connect an Azure virtual network to an on-prem network device or server, making the cloud network part of your corporate network
- VPN Point-to-site connection, with which you can make a machine that is not in the cloud part of your cloud network
- Eventually you could deploy an expressroute connection, connecting your Azure deployments to your datacenter over MPLS. I mention this for the sake of completeness, you don't want this now. :)